# Using AJAX to run a webservice in the background

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I basically need to do this, but unfortunately my hosting provider doesn't give me "Full Trust" so I can't run threads. Is there a way to do this using AJAX?

```
//Updates Information in Database
Thread threadFind = new Thread(LoadFind);
threadFind.Start();

Response.Write("Send old information to users");
```

I don't want my users to have to wait at all for a response, so I can send them the old information. However, while they are on the page I want another thread (or something that works like a thread) to update the information for the next user that visits.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add a little more detail on what exactly your scenario is?

Comment: Spawning a new `Thread` or using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` seems to work under Medium Trust in IIS 7.5. What trust level does your hosting provider have you set at?

Comment: Anyway, spawning new threads in a web application is not a really good idea, if you are planning any scalability.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can play with asynchronous pages:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a service, that is callable through HttpGet (via WCF, or a simple ASHX handler) and call it from JS (using JQuery's .ajax() or .get() methods for example).